# resource.data.cid == request.auth.uid Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I get the error code "permission-denied" with error message "Missing or insuffiecient permisions" and I'm not sure why, I'm new to this.

Here is the rule defined in firestore:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function depositRecordAuth() {
      return request.auth != null &&
      resource.data.cid == request.auth.uid &&
      timestamp.value(request.auth.token.expires)>= request.time;
    }
    match /deposit/{docId} {
      allow read , delete: if
                               depositRecordAuth();
    }
  }
}
```

And the only piece of code which throws the error is: resource.data.cid == request.auth.uid
If I remove it, it will work.

An this is the code which throws the error:

```js
fireStoreDocListener = (collection: string, docId: string, CallBack: (data: firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined) => void) =>
  this.firestore?.collection(collection).doc(docId)
  .onSnapshot((doc) => {
    const docData = doc.data();
    CallBack(docData);
  }, (err: IFireBaseError) => {
    let errorDescription = "";
    if (err.code === 'permission-denied') {
      //do somthing
      errorDescription = `firebase error on doc listener , error code - ${err.code} , error message - ${err.message}`;
    } else {
      //do somthing else
      errorDescription = `firebase error on doc listener , error code - ${err.code} , error message - ${err.message}'`;
    }

  })
```

Updated with logging:
the console.log(collection, docId) has
Collection:  deposit
docId:  109003

and the doc in firebase:
[doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVAi9.png)

Comment: Can you `console.log(collection, docId)` at the start of your function and share a screenshot of the output? And a screenshot of a document from Firestore console that you think should be returned in the query?

Comment: Also: which of your three conditions is not being met? I.e. if you disable them all, and then enable them one by one, which condition is calling the read to fail?

Comment: this condition is not being met: resource.data.cid == request.auth.uid